# Is there a way to define a constant array in PHP?

Tags: php

Is there a way to define a constant array in PHP?

Comment: It can be used to emulate enums, although everything can be done with classes and a bit of reflection.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it's not possible. From the manual: [**Constants Syntax**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.syntax.php)

> Only scalar data (boolean, integer, float and string) can be contained in constants. It is possible to define constants as a resource, but it should be avoided, as it can cause unexpected results.

If you need to set a defined set of constants, consider creating a class and filling it with [**class constants**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php). A slightly modified example from the manual:

```
class MyClass
{
const constant1 = 'constant value';
const constant2 = 'constant value';
const constant3 = 'constant value';

  function showConstant1() {
    echo  self::constant1 . "\n";
  }
}

echo MyClass::constant3;
```

Also check out the link GhostDog posted, it's a nice workaround.

Answer (score 8):

```
define('SOMEARRAY', serialize(array(1,2,3)));

$is_in_array = in_array($x, unserialize(SOMEARRAY));
```

That's the closest to an array constant.

Comment: Thanx: did this and worked great      
    define("DEF_ARR", serialize(array("1", "a", "From.ME.to.YOU")));
    
    foreach (unserialize(DEF_ARR) as $k=>$v) {
     echo "Key: ".$k."  VALUE: ".$v."\n";
    }

Answer (score 2):

You can not, but you can just define static array in a class and it would serve you just the same, just instead of FOO you'd write Foo::$bar.

Answer (score 1):

don't think you can. But you can always try [searching](http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/package/4226.html).

Comment: The downvote is unjustified, the link points to a very good resource.

Comment: can you review your answer? There is a seemingly contradiction between "don't think you can" and the reference's "This class provides an alternative solution that can be used to also declare array values as constants."